# What value should WINVER be for Windows 10?

Tags: visual-c++, visual-c++-2022

In my `stdafx.h` file I have:

```
#ifndef WINVER              // Allow use of features specific to Windows 2000 or later.
#define WINVER 0x0501       // Change this to the appropriate value to target other versions of Windows.
#endif
```

How do I find out what the value should be for Windows 10? I want this to be the minimum supported platform for my MFC project now.

Comment: That is not how you enforce it.  Use Project > Properties > Linker > System > "Minimum required version" = 10.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to build using APIs that are available in Windows 10 or later, then you'd use:

```
#include <winsdkver.h>
#ifndef _WIN32_WINNT
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0A00
#endif
#include <sdkddkver.h>
```

See [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/porting/modifying-winver-and-win32-winnt).

Per the comment, you probably *also* want to set the linker minimum supported OS to 10.0.